# Error within Replication API

Tags: api

In an effort to try to copy the Opportunity object data from our customer using the Replication API, we received an API error and were forced to use the SOQL based non-replicated API which performs slower. Can someone please help by letting me know what are my options here or why do we get this error or how to debug this.

Object: Opportunity
Message: RefreshReplicated
Exception:

> ```
> AxisFault faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
> ```
>
> faultSubcode: faultString: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>   faultActor: faultNode: faultDetail:
>   {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketException:
>   Connection reset at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)  at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
>   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:534)
>   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:489)
>   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
>   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:820)
>   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
>   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)  at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:181)
>   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)  at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:107)
>   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)  at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:221) 
>   at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141) 
>   at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:90)  at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(Unknown
>   Source)  at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source) 
>   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) 
>   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) 
>   at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
>   at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)  at
>   org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)  at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
>   at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)  at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)  at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)  at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443) at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366) at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812) at
>   com.sforce.soap.partner.SoapBindingStub.retrieve(SoapBindingStub.java:2980)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SoapBindingStubWrapper.retrieve(SoapBindingStubWrapper.java:102)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SalesforceLoader.retrieveData(SalesforceLoader.java:3380)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.RefreshStrategyBase.loadIncrementalInsertsAndUpdates(RefreshStrategyBase.java:389)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.RefreshStrategyReplicated.processObject(RefreshStrategyReplicated.java:64)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SalesforceBaseDaemon.callStrategy(SalesforceBaseDaemon.java:1274)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SalesforceBaseDaemon.processObjects(SalesforceBaseDaemon.java:1156)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SalesforceBaseDaemon.processAllObjectsAndRetryIfNeeded(SalesforceBaseDaemon.java:440)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SalesforceBaseDaemon.run(SalesforceBaseDaemon.java:324)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.util.WorkerThreadPool$WorkerThread.runIDaemon(WorkerThreadPool.java:810)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.util.WorkerThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(WorkerThreadPool.java:759)
>   {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:loader4.prod.cloud9analytics.com
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at
>
> ```
> org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)  at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:701)  at
> ```
>
> org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)  at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
>   at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)  at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)  at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)  at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)  at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)  at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)  at
>   com.sforce.soap.partner.SoapBindingStub.retrieve(SoapBindingStub.java:2980)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SoapBindingStubWrapper.retrieve(SoapBindingStubWrapper.java:102)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SalesforceLoader.retrieveData(SalesforceLoader.java:3380)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.RefreshStrategyBase.loadIncrementalInsertsAndUpdates(RefreshStrategyBase.java:389)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.RefreshStrategyReplicated.processObject(RefreshStrategyReplicated.java:64)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SalesforceBaseDaemon.callStrategy(SalesforceBaseDaemon.java:1274)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SalesforceBaseDaemon.processObjects(SalesforceBaseDaemon.java:1156)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SalesforceBaseDaemon.processAllObjectsAndRetryIfNeeded(SalesforceBaseDaemon.java:440)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.salesforce.loader.SalesforceBaseDaemon.run(SalesforceBaseDaemon.java:324)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.util.WorkerThreadPool$WorkerThread.runIDaemon(WorkerThreadPool.java:810)
>   at
>   com.certive.cs.util.WorkerThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(WorkerThreadPool.java:759)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset  at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)  at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
>   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:534)
>   at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:489)
>   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
>   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:820)
>   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
>   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)  at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:181)
>   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)  at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:107)
>   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)  at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:221) 
>   at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141) 
>   at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:90)  at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(Unknown
>   Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source) 
>   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source) at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) 
>   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) 
>   at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext
>
> ```
> ***** Thu Jul 30 11:45:33 EDT 2014 *****
> Title: Opportunity
> Message: Switching to non-replicated strategy
> ***** Thu Jul 30 11:45:33 EDT 2014 *****
> ```

Answer (score 1):

So the proximate cause of your issue is that the network had a hiccup. This bit here:

```
Server.userException faultSubcode: faultString: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset faultActor: faultNode: faultDetail: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168) at
```

You'll notice has several instances of "Connection Reset". This is generally an indication that your network had a hiccup. Either your wifi dropped or your router got confused for a second, or a random quark hit your ISP's router at just the right angle to make it go "huh?" for half a second. Have you retried with the replication api?